# How can I tell TeXstudio not always to update MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, texstudio, windows

**Update**: I re-installed MiKTeX and updated MiKTeX console (admin first, then "normal" console).

Then I re-installed TeXstudio, but it is still not stable and requests MiKTeX updates and cryptic `INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode -ini "&pdflatex hJCqMsk \dump"` information

---

I just started to use TeXstudio and it works really great. However, I am on Windows and it regularly requests to update MiKTeX (which causes a popup concerning admin rights). Please see below for a log file.

```
Prozess gestartet: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "MoodlePruefungMusterloesung".tex
Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\sqc\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
Kommando abgestürzt: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "MoodlePruefungMusterloesung".tex
Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)
```

**What I can exclude:**

- It is not a remote repo. The whole folder is under C:/... (ok, the path is a bit longer ;-) )
- The package did not change since a long time and e.g. today, the update process started about 8 times. Again with cryptic names as below.
- The c-drive is not encrypted or anything like that.
- To my best knowledge, I allowed each installation and I can't find any error or typo in the rendered pdf.
- I saved my tex-files
- I also updated Miktex

[image]

**My script body:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{a4wide,german,fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstset{%numbers=right, 
    numberstyle=\tiny, 
    breaklines=true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},
    numbersep=5pt,
    xleftmargin=0.5cm,
    xrightmargin=0cm} 

\setcounter{page}{0}
\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}
\lhead{\textsf{Probeprüfung Moodle \\}}

\rhead{\textsf{Bachelor of Science FHO in Wirtschaftsingenieurwesen \\ MOSIM}}

\lfoot{\textsf{\tiny \copyright FHS St.Gallen | Fachbereich Bau und Technik | SQC | \today}}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\textsf{Seite \thepage \ von 21}}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} 

% Abkürzungen
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcommand\filledcirc{{\color{black}\bullet}}
\newcommand{\mcode}[1]{\colorbox{lightgray}{\lstinline{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

**log in the folder of the .tex file**:

```
MoodlePruefungMusterloesung.log is empty
```

**The log file from C:\Users\sqc\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log**

```
2019-12-09 17:07:35,412+0100 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode MoodlePruefungMusterloesung.tex
2019-12-09 17:07:35,412+0100 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2019-12-09 17:07:35,412+0100 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2019-12-09 17:07:35,601+0100 INFO  pdflatex - installing package oberdiek triggered by tex/latex/oberdiek\epstopdf.sty
2019-12-09 17:07:37,927+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2019-12-09 17:07:37,927+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2019-12-09 17:07:37,927+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository: http://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2019-12-09 17:07:38,112+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository digest: a6cb6c9187fb4e420ce11bbc10b57326
2019-12-09 17:07:38,888+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to download 17301207 bytes
2019-12-09 17:07:38,888+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to install 180 file(s) (1 package(s))
2019-12-09 17:07:39,479+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: downloading http://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/oberdiek.tar.lzma...
2019-12-09 17:07:41,516+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: 17.30 MB, 68.25 Mbit/s
2019-12-09 17:07:41,686+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: extracting files from oberdiek.tar.lzma...
2019-12-09 17:07:45,488+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The installed file does not exist.
2019-12-09 17:07:45,488+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\epstopdf.sty"
2019-12-09 17:07:45,488+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\findfile.cpp
2019-12-09 17:07:45,488+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 59
2019-12-09 17:07:45,488+0100 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
2019-12-09 17:09:42,562+0100 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode MoodlePruefungMusterloesung.tex
2019-12-09 17:09:42,570+0100 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2019-12-09 17:09:42,570+0100 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2019-12-09 17:09:43,257+0100 INFO  pdflatex - installing package oberdiek triggered by tex/latex/oberdiek\epstopdf.sty
2019-12-09 17:09:46,033+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2019-12-09 17:09:46,034+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2019-12-09 17:09:46,034+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository: http://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2019-12-09 17:09:46,357+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository digest: a6cb6c9187fb4e420ce11bbc10b57326
2019-12-09 17:09:48,388+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to download 17301207 bytes
2019-12-09 17:09:48,391+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to install 180 file(s) (1 package(s))
2019-12-09 17:09:50,292+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: downloading http://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/oberdiek.tar.lzma...
2019-12-09 17:09:51,806+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: 17.30 MB, 91.66 Mbit/s
2019-12-09 17:09:52,070+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: extracting files from oberdiek.tar.lzma...
2019-12-09 17:09:59,688+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The installed file does not exist.
2019-12-09 17:09:59,689+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\epstopdf.sty"
2019-12-09 17:09:59,689+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\findfile.cpp
2019-12-09 17:09:59,689+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 59
2019-12-09 17:09:59,689+0100 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
```

Comment: My German is not what it use to be, are you sure it is not attempting to install some missing package. We have had someone else complain about this and nobody knows where it comes from

Comment: Where do all the curious names come from? Are your files on some special drive that is encrypted or synced regularly?

Comment: Unfortunately the quoted messages are not very informative. Usually I would not expect your editor to try to update MikTeX. It is much more likely that some missing package triggers the on-the-fly package distribution. If you allow MikTeX to install the missing package the window should not pop up again. Sometimes the MikTeX package database goes out of sync. In that case fully update your MikteX via the Console (update once in User and once in Admin mode) and then run *Tasks > Update package database* once in Admin and once in User mode.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think the file names are the names TeXstudio comes up with if people don't save their files (usually the files with those weird names live in a temporary folder). Some of these may also come from the preview compile feature.

Comment: Just wondering, are your files on some kind of cloud drive like onedrive or Dropbox?

Comment: What log file is that? from the editor? Please also provide the real log file (both might be interesting here). Note that the error log shown by the editor I often unusable for us as its filtering are commonly wrong.

Comment: go to the package section. Update the package database by clicking on the icon with the arrow. sort the list by "packaged on" and then look for uninstalled, new (everything from the last two month) packages and install them. Then run the update manager. Do the same in user mode.

Comment: The oberdiek package is currently split up in smaller packages. It can confuse your miktex if your package database is not up-to-date, it then looks for a missing package in the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea who triggers the format creation here. Your messages above regarding oberdiek were obvious but this looks like a texstudio problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do think installing Miktex + Texstudio in C:/ would perhaps help?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I really have no clue - just one example `Kommando abgestürzt: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "VvJQQc".tex Prozess endete mit Fehler(n)`. What can I do? As discribed in the question, it seems, an update process gets startet - but why?

Comment: pdflatex is not an update process but a compilation. I have no idea why texstudio starts it. Try to disable all "preview" functions.